# RaspberryPi Stopwatch (TKinter) with Trigger

Tags: python-3.x, triggers, raspberry-pi, watch, gpio

i would like to build a stopwatch for my carrera track which i built a little bit bigger.
So I have bought a Raspberry Pi 3 with an additional 7 "touch screen and the individual modules for triggering.
Everything works fine individually.

Now I found a great stopwatch on the net which I also used. Works really great.

In another script, that I've written by myself, the triggering with the gpios works also fantastic.

Now I want to combine both and fail.

Does anyone have an idea or suggested solution where my mistake is?

Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import tkinter as tk
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO_TRIGGER_PIN = 17
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(GPIO_TRIGGER_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

def update_timeText():
if (state):
    global timer
    timer[2] += 1
    if (timer[2] >= 100):
        timer[2] = 0
        timer[1] += 1
    if (timer[1] >= 60):
        timer[0] += 1
        timer[1] = 0
    timeString = pattern.format(timer[0], timer[1], timer[2])
    timeText.configure(text=timeString)
root.after(10, update_timeText)

def start():
    global state
    state = True
    print('Pressed Start')

def stop():
    global state
    state = False
    print('Pressed Stop')

def reset():
    global timer
    timer = [0, 0, 0]
    timeText.configure(text='00:00:00')
    print('Pressed Reset')

while GPIO.input(GPIO_TRIGGER_PIN) == True:
    if GPIO.input(GPIO_TRIGGER_PIN):
        print('CAR DETECTED')
    time.sleep(0.1)

state = False

# BULDING TKinter GUI
root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_title('Stopwatch')

timer = [0, 0, 0]
pattern = '{0:02d}:{1:02d}:{2:02d}'

timeText = tk.Label(root, text="00:00:00", font=("Helvetica", 150))
timeText.pack()

startButton = tk.Button(root, text='Start', command=start)
startButton.pack()

stopButton = tk.Button(root, text='Stop', command=stop)
stopButton.pack()

resetButton = tk.Button(root, text='Reset', command=reset)
resetButton.pack()

update_timeText()
root.mainloop()
```

Currently I get the trigger in the console as output "CAR DETECTED". However, I do not get the TKinter panel.
If I remove

```
while GPIO.input(GPIO_TRIGGER_PIN) == True:
    if GPIO.input(GPIO_TRIGGER_PIN):
        print('CAR DETECTED')
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

then the display appears and works. Without triggering.
If I put it all down, I get also the panel but it also triggers nothing more.
Any ideas ?

Thanks for help

Comment: I think you want `GPIO.add_event_detect()` to add a callback. But it is unclear what you want to happen when a gpio event happens.

Comment: Hello Johnny. Thanks for your quick reply. When the car triggers, I would like to stop the clock. That's all in the end. With the buttons reset and start I can start them again and everything begins from beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Not really my area of expertise, but since nobody else answered, I'll give it a shot.

I think you want to use [`GPIO.add_event_callback()`](http://tieske.github.io/rpi-gpio/modules/GPIO.html#add_event_callback)* to add a callback that gets called when an event happens.

```
# Callback function
def on_trigger(channel_number):
    # Just update the flag
    global state
    state = False

# Set the callback
GPIO.add_event_callback(GPIO_TRIGGER_PIN , callback=on_trigger)
```

Then, delete the `while` loop.

---

*According to the docs, you need the darksidesync library to use this function. Instead of the callback, you could also create a separate thread. Personally, I would prefer the callback.

```
from threading import Thread

def thread_function(arg):
    global state
    # Listen for state change
    while GPIO.input(GPIO_TRIGGER_PIN) == True:
        if GPIO.input(GPIO_TRIGGER_PIN):
            # Update var
            state = False
            print('CAR DETECTED')
        time.sleep(0.1)

thread = Thread(target = thread_function)
thread.start()
```

Hope this helps.